# Open folder for a given path in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, finder

Let's say I have a path to a folder in a text document or in the clipboard, for example:

```
/Users/Joe/Documents/workspace/test
```

How can I quickly open this folder in Mac OS X?
In Windows I could open the Run-dialog, paste the path into the input box and the folder would open.

Is there a similar way in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Yes, there are. If you are already in Finder you can use one of them:

1. In the `Go` menu, choose `Go to Folder…` option
2. Press <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

If you want to do it from Dock - press and hold left mouse on Finder icon and choose `Go to Folder…`.

Just paste in modal window your path and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

It will throw an error if the folder does not exist, or the path points to a file. Note also that it opens in your current window, so if you want to Go in a new window you will have to open that window first.

Comment: It would also be interesting to know why Apple thought it was a good idea to make it so obscure that folks would need to Google the answer. Just make the root directory a favorite et viola' problem solved. Nope. :(

Comment: Option 2) for ordinary guys: Ctrl + Command + G

Comment: I'm going to write this on a post-it. I use this *just* infrequently enough I forget it

Comment: In my case, it is `SHIFT` + `COMMAND` + `G`

Comment: So intuitive and discoverable.

Answer (score 37):

If you are working at the command line try

```
$ open <path>
```

with the bonus that it also opens files in the default application that is set for them.

Answer (score 7):

If it is a network path, go to finder and click <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then type `smb://servername/drive/file`

Comment: A bit late to comment, but the `smb://` made all the difference!