# How to use exact path in Mac OS X open file dialog?

Tags: macos, file-management

How do I to use the exact path in the Mac OS X open file dialog?

```
/Users/username/Workspaces/Enide-2015/_ws/atom.ico
```

I have found this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/44086/open-folder-for-a-given-path-in-mac-os-x), but there are still few extra clicks. There is also this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/640217/how-to-cut-paste-file-path-in-mac-os-file-open-dialog), but I still have to click in filter that is `*.gif` by default.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean but to open a specific file just drag and drop it on the dialog.

Comment: I have to agree with @user309603, could you [edit] your question to be a little more specific at what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 6):

You can use Command+Shift+G in this dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't. You're referring to the "Go to folder" action that does only that.

If you want the functionality you describe, you could probably: 1) Make a Services menu Automator workflow that displays a dialog prompting for text, then opens the file at the path indicated; then, 2) Assign a global keyboard shortcut to this Service using the Keyboard preferences pane. This probably isn't much easier to use than just using Spotlight to find the file ( <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>, type file name, <kbd>Enter</kbd> = open), and you won't get Tab completion this way either.